# Bash script multiple commands issue

Tags: linux, bash, xterm

I am currently working on a program that needs to boot a program automatically whenever it registers that this program is not open already. It needs superuser rights to boot.
Currently, I have a working Bash script, looking as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do #Continue indefinitely

    if [ $(ps aux | grep '/odroid_detection' | grep -v '<defunct>' -c) -le 4 ]; then #if less than 3 odroid_servers are active (booter opens 3 processes)
        xterm -iconic -e su -c "xterm -iconic -hold /home/odroid/Documents/SUNRISE-Odroid/_odroid_detection/_odroid_detection/bin/Debug/_odroid_detection" 
    fi

    sleep 60 #check every minute

done
```

The program that executes, however, is not working exactly as planned because it is executed from the root map instead of the map it is in. I therefore want to cd to the map the executable is in (~/Documents/SUNRISE-Odroid/_odroid_detection/_odroid_detection/bin/Debug) but have the same functionality as mentioned above. This is what I came up with:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do #Continue indefinitely

    if [ $(ps aux | grep '/odroid_detection' | grep -v '<defunct>' -c) -le 4 ]; then #if less than 3 odroid_servers are active (booter opens 3 processes) 
        xterm -iconic -e "cd ../_odroid_detection/_odroid_detection/bin/Debug/ && su -c "xterm -iconic -hold -e _odroid_detection""
    fi

    sleep 60 #check every minute

done
```

This does not work, however, and I have tried many alternatives but I cannot seem to get it working.. It gives the following errors in the terminal:

```
xterm: Can't execvp cd ../_odroid_detection/_odroid_detection/bin/Debug && su -c xterm: No such file or directory
```

The xterm that gives this error opens in the map ~/Documents/SUNRISE-Odroid/Bash, and executing the cd mentioned above does work when I execute it seperately, so I do not understand why it cannot find the file or directory.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not related to the bash-question. Did you consider using [`supervisor`](http://supervisord.org/) for this? This is the exact type of thing that supervisor does; keep X number of processes alive (via the `numprocs` config setting).

Comment: As documented in `man xterm`, `-e` takes a program and its arguments as a parameter, not a command list. You can run `bash` as the program, though.

Comment: Okay, the colouring of StackOverflow made me understand one mistake that I made: the starting quote after 'su -c' gets interpreted as an ending quote of the xterm execute line. 
I now have a working program, will post the solution in a bit.

Comment: @Dencker Thank you for your suggestion, I did not know of this package. Will look into that!

Answer (score 0):

The colouring of StackOverflow made me understand one mistake that I made: the starting quote after 'su -c' gets interpreted as an ending quote of the xterm execute line. The working code is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do #Continue indefinitely

    if [ $(ps aux | grep '/odroid_detection' | grep -v '<defunct>' -c) -le 2 ]; then #if less than 3 odroid_servers are active (booter opens 3 processes)
        xterm -iconic -e "cd ../_odroid_detection/_odroid_detection/bin/Debug/ && su -c ./_odroid_detection"
    fi

    sleep 60 #check every minute

done
```